# Select and highlight row in pivot table that contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that selects and highlight a row in the pivot table that contains a specific text.

Right now I have it selecting the exact match (screenshot below). Is there a way to make it select all rows with "JPY", instead of typing them out one by one?

[Current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3yps.png)

[Result in pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l95po.png)

Btw, conditional formatting doesn't work on this one because this pivot table gets deleted after each run and so pivot-table specific CF gets deleted as well.I know, poor design but it's too late to change it because this is linked to two other processes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code - but update the PIVOT FIELDS NAME on LINE 3 first. 
This should do what you want it to do.

```
Sub Highlight_JPY_Pairs()

Dim element, cell As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ENTER-NAME-OF-FIELD-CONTAINING-JPY-TEXT")
    .ClearAllFilters

    For Each element In .DataRange
        If element.Value Like "*JPY*" Then
            element.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            element.End(xlToRight).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```